# Loaded SWF gets slower

Tags: flash, load

Hi am making a game involving a number of balls that move across the screen. Everything works fine and dandy when I play the SWF on its own, but when I load it into another SWF, animation become increasingly choppy with time.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check the memory and cpu performace when you play the swf in standalone mode and loaded by another swf. Have you performed any profiling or memory leaking testes ?

Comment: Sorry for incorrect given information, actually I do not care about performance, i just wanna know why loaded swf into another get slower, it seems like fps decreased, animation gets slower twice...

Comment: If your standalone swf runs at 50fps for example and you load it inside another swf that runs at 24fps then both swf's will run at 24fps. Make sure your both swf's run the same framerate :)

Comment: Your last comment give an answer! Thx